# Status of Armhf Kenetic build for Jessie or other recommendation

Tags: ros, beagleboneblack, ros-kinetic, jessie

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see that Kinetics does not list Jessie armhf as a ready release
http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation

I note that the last question about this dates back to July.
http://answers.ros.org/question/239466/incomplete-packages-for-kinetic-armhf-jessie/

I am in the same situation as that poster, preferring the Jessie distribution on the BeagleBone Black.
Can someone update the status?  I guess if this Jessie armhf build has been pending since July I shouldn't hold my breath.
I will only need modest ROS functionality to operate a panel with an ARM BBB board
tethered to the vehicle with another ARM BBB board, over Ethernet.
What do you advise?  Building from source?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254907/status-of-armhf-kenetic-build-for-jessie-or-other-recommendation/) by [dcrawford](https://answers.ros.org/users/29362/dcrawford/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no update since http://answers.ros.org/question/239466/incomplete-packages-for-kinetic-armhf-jessie/ and is not expected to be a change.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0